Airdrop жетона на блокчейне ton
Как сделать airdrop жетона, который был выпущен через ton minter. Все сайты перешерстил. Ничего не нашёл. Backend на node v20.
Выпустил жетон на ton minter. И уже неделю не могу раздать жетоны пользователям приложения. Все мои попытки были неудачными. Всё статьи перечитал

Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO!  рекомендую ознакомиться со справкой => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
